# LINQ to SQL and Column Alias with spaces

Tags: linq-to-sql

Still a bit new to Linq. This is driving me nuts. I want to alias a column, the alias should have a space.

This works fine:

```
Dim q = From tmp in t.Table Select iDate = tmp.iDate
```

But, I want this to work

```
Dim q = From tmp in t.Table Select "Some Alias With Space" = tmp.iDate
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't use space characters in variable names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all Alias's can't have spaces, just like any variable name can't have a space.  My question tho is why would you want/need to have a space in your name?  I'm sure there are better means of accomplishing what your trying to achieve with out trying to institute bad practices of bad naming conventions.

Comment: You can only have a space in your alias if you are using T-SQL, Select * from Mytable [My table Name]. But like david said, there is no point to having a space in your code. If you really needed to, use the _

Comment: Thanks! The reason for looking for a space is b/c the data returned is in an IList

"Return q.ToList"

At this point I simply bind this to a rad grid. The grid column header takes the column names. I was looking for a simple approach for spaces in the column header on the grid.

Knowing that alias can't have spaces I will modify the header manually. Thanks for the quick responses!

Answer (score 2):

Use Square Bracket to use alias in **LinqToSql** like

```
[Some Alias With Space] = tmp.iDate
```

if this wont work then remove white space and use `[]`

Answer (score 2):

Use simple alias before the column or columns:

```
var x = from data in mdc.Accounts
select new
{
    data.AccountName,
    Total = data.CashAndEquivalent + data.MarginBalance
};

//Total is the alias
```

Answer (score 1):

**BY USING DATA TABLE**

```
DataTable dt = (from x in obj.GetAllReqVSTFs()
                select new
                    {
                        VSTF_id = x.VSTF_id,
                        x.Description,
                        x.PM1,
                        x.PM2,
                        x.Analyst_Status,
                        x.Overall_Status,
                        x.Planed_Analyst_End_Date
                    }).Take(5).ToList().ToDataTable();
foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
{
    c.ColumnName = c.ColumnName.Replace("_", " ");
}

gvBurntHours.DataSource = dt;
gvBurntHours.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't do this because columns alias must be valid C# identifiers, and they don't allow whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it for databinding to gridview [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/1331413.aspx?How%20can%20I%20create%20a%20space%20in%20my%20column%20name%20with%20LINQ%20) example could work:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var db = new MyDataContextDataContext())
        {
            var bl2 = (from b in db.Table1 
                          select new{b.AttendanceDate, Course = b.CourseCode + " - " + b.CourseSection, b.CourseName, TeacherName = b.StaffLastName + ", " + b.StaffFirstName}
                          );

            grd.DataSource = bl2;
            grd.DataBind();  
        }
    }

    
        protected void grd_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header){
                e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Attendance Date";
                e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "Course Code and Section";
                e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "Course Name";
                e.Row.Cells[3].Text = "Teacher Name";
    
            }
        }
    
        <asp:GridView ID="grd" class="table table-striped" runat="server" OnRowCreated="grd_RowCreated">
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                None
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't, sorry.  Hell, if you bring a table with a space in the name into Linq it will automatically replace the space with underscores.

Besides it not being possible, it is an extremely overwhelmingly bad idea.  Something that people that wrote Access should be shot because of.